# Get a warning messages on system logs ?

Tags: macos, logs

I started for some reason OSX's Log console and just found out someone was attacking me with ssh connexion's

I had over 500 of these messages (just the user name was chaging) in 5 minutes :

```
23/09/13 14:55:04,638 sshd[18830]: error: PAM: unknown user for illegal user crystal from 193.183.98.218 via 192.168.0.12
```

Do you know a way to get some kind of warning popup when a process sends a lot of logs like here ?

Comment: Get the application called Little Snitch.

Comment: Do you have access to the computer with IP 192.168.0.12?

Comment: Hard to say what it is, but for blocking it, please take a look at this question which may help http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94282/how-to-block-internet-traffic-of-an-application

Comment: @patrix it's my ip behind my NAT router.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to monitor the console for a specific message and send an alert.

However, there is a alternative approaches to monitoring or even block a specific ssh activity.

Without taking any credit (other than finding it), I would advice you to look up at some suggested solutions here that might apply to your situation.

[Getting notified when someone logs into a server using SSH or Remote Desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45688/getting-notified-when-someone-logs-into-a-server-using-ssh-or-remote-desktop)